# Access iTunes store programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, itunes-store

I know there is an affiliate program with iTunes that rewards you money if you drive a user of your app to go buy a song on iTunes store. Is it possible to query the iTunes Store beforehand, in an app, and perhaps play the 1:30 musical sample for a commercial purpose? Let's imagine shazam, which allows you to go buy a song on iTunes (and makes money from it): could they provide a 1:30 music sample of the song you just detected?

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not. Apple provides APIs to query their content, even on iTunes. [See documentation](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html)

You could easily make a query to the search iTunes store API, specifying `audio`
 as media and then use the `previewUrl`, described as:

> A URL referencing the 30-second preview file for the content
>   associated with the returned media type.

You can stream the music in your app before letting the user following the link to the store.
Possible library for that: [SoundManager](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SoundManager).